# Class name as idempotent typecast function

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, casting

I'm writing a custom type `Foo` and I'd like to achieve the following: when writing

```
foo = Foo(bar)
```

then if `bar` is already an instance of `Foo`, then `Foo(foo)` returns that object unmodified, so `foo` and `bar` refer to the same object. Otherwise a new object of type `Foo` should be created, using information from `bar` in whatever way `Foo.__init__` deems appropriate.

How can I do this?

I would assume that `Foo.__new__` is the key to this. It should be fairly easy to have `Foo.__new__` return the existing object if the `instanceof` check succeeds, and to call `super().__new__` otherwise. But [the documentation for `__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) writes this:

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of *cls*, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where *self* is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to `__new__()`.

In this case I would be returning an instance of the requested class, albeit not a new one. Can I somehow prevent the call to `__init__`? Or do I have to add a check inside `__init__` to detect whether it is being invoked for a newly created instance or for an already existing one? The latter sounds like code duplication which should be avoidable.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use factory methods to achieve this?

Comment: @Tagc: I'm kind of used to using constructor names for casts. For example `float(x)`, `str(x)` or `tuple(x)` do return the same object if it already is of the correct type. I am using that notation quite often, so I want it for my own types as well, to be consistent. So it's a question of style, I guess. Functionally a factory method would of course work just as fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO, you should directly use `__new__` and `__init__`. The test in init to see whether you should init a new object or already have an existing one is so simple that there is no code duplication and the added complexity is IMHO acceptable

```
class Foo:
    def __new__(cls, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, cls):
            print("New: same object")
            return obj
        else:
            print("New: create object")
            return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self, obj):
        if self is obj:
            print("init: same object")
        else:
            print("init: brand new object from ", obj)
            # do the actual initialization
```

It gives as expected:

```
>>> foo = Foo("x")
New: create object
init: brand new object from  x
>>> bar = Foo(foo)
New: same object
init: same object
>>> bar is foo
True
```

Comment: The `self is arg` pattern is neat, hadn't thought about that. I guess I'll still end up writing a metaclass for this, in order to introduce this check automatically into constructors of derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by moving the required code into a metaclass like this:

```
class IdempotentCast(type):
    """Metaclass to ensure that Foo(x) is x if isinstance(x, Foo)"""
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds):
        res = None
        defineNew = all(i.__new__ is object.__new__ for i in bases)
        if defineNew:
            def n(cls, *args, **kwds):
                if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], cls) and not kwds:
                    return args[0]
                else:
                    return super(res, cls).__new__(cls)
            namespace["__new__"] = n
        realInit = namespace.get("__init__")
        if realInit is not None or defineNew:
            @functools.wraps(realInit)
            def i(self, *args, **kwds):
                if len(args) != 1 or args[0] is not self:
                    if realInit is None:
                        return super(res, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
                    else:
                        return realInit(self, *args, **kwds)
            namespace["__init__"] = i
        res = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)
        return res

class Foo(metaclass=IdempotentCast):
    ...
```

That metaclass adds a `__new__` method unless there exists a base class that already added a `__new__` method. So for class hierarchies where some such class extends another such class, the `__new__` method will get added but once. It also wraps the constructor to perform the check whether the first argument is identical to `self` (thanks to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41890600/1468366) by [Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta) for pointing out this simple check). Otherwise it calls the original constructor, or the base constructor if no constructor had been defined.

Quite a bit of code, but you only need that once, and can use it to introduce these semantics for as many types as you want. If you only need this for a single class, other answers may be more appropriate.